# Why does "top: 100%;" not work on relative but is taken into consideration if animated?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here is a typical css layout for this,

```
.rel {
   background: brown;
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   top: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I have made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/xdA68/) to show what relative and absolute do with a `top: 100%;`.

In the same [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/xdA68/), click on the second red div, and watch as it acts as if it was positioned 100% down.

Is this odd or what? The div when animated is taking the `top: 100%;` into consideration but on a normal situation it does nothing.

*Edit*

With adding,

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Will allow you to use the `top: 100%;` but why does `.animate();` take the top into consideration when the element its self is not?

Comment: Not sure how it **should** look.. but here is the result after setting `html,body{height:100%}`.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5BjHT/

Comment: Hmm very interesting I added that to my html and body before without any effect taking place. Maybe I was working on a different fiddle but, any idea on why the element once animated slides up as if it was on the bottom without a height on the `html`/`body` tag?

Comment: It's because the height is relevant to the parent. In this instance, the parent being body, with a height of 0 by default. Setting 100%, will allow the children to also use a height of 100%, as previously 100% of 0 was 0.... as for why it worked before, I am guessing the elements were within a contained parent, whos height was defined with an absolute value.

Comment: Okay! Well I am going to delete this question because it has little to no importance for future use I would assume. Just me miss understanding how a css style works.

Comment: You never know. It may helpful in the future. Most questions on here are localized, yet still have relevance in the future. Aside from that, can you delete a question with an answer? I didn't think you could.

Comment: I just deleted it but I saw a comment I didn't read so I reversed that, I guess it can be deleted with an answer. If it may be useful for someone I'll leave it. I am surprised to how little information there is on this though. It was a pain to find the question I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your instance, a `height` of 100% is needed on the `body`/`html` if you want `top` to work, relative to the height of the window.

`html, body { height:100%; }` [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5BjHT/)

Given the current example, the parent element, `body`, has dimensions defined based on its containing children. Since the child elements have a height of `100px`, that means that the `body` then also has a height of `100px`, as those are the only elements that exist within it. Thus, `top:100%` will have absolutely no effect on the containing elements, as these elements determine the dimensions of the parent.

In order for `top:100%` to work, the parent element's height has to be directly defined, as opposed to being expanded based on the children elements. Something like `top:222px` [**would work**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5BjHT/2/), as that is an absolute value from the top. But using `%` based values requires dimensions, as `100%` of 0 is also 0. You could set the parent, `body` to `height:500px` [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5BjHT/1/), and it would work. But if you want it based upon the window's height, then `body, html { height:100% }` would be required.

As for why the animation itself works using jQuery, it is because `px` based values are used to move the element in the DOM, rather than percentage based ones. Thus this would work in plain CSS too (stated above). Taking a look at the code during the animation demonstrates this, [**here is a screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BWJJ.png). As you can see, `px` values are used to move the element. The only difference is that jQuery makes the calculation to figure out the height of the window. Other than that, jQuery isn't doing anything special that would otherwise be unachievable in pure CSS. You could do the exact same thing using a CSS animation, assuming `px` values are used... but that is no longer an issue as you now know to set the height of the parent element, enabling you to use percentage based values instead.

Comment: Yeah I had the question really poorly worded so I cut out the bad information. Once again thanks a bunch for such a great answer! It had more information then I could of dreamed for ha.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: As JoshC has stated this would solve the problem for future regular uses but why would the element once animated take the `top: 100%;` into consideration?

Comment: So if I animated it with `css` only, would it have the same effect?

Comment: @JoshC Thanks a lot mate! I disregarded andygoestohollywood's comment because it was not constructive in anyway but once Mohammad said that's correct I had an idea about css animations.

Comment: @JoshPowell Because jQuery takes this initial CSS parameters just as reference, it then poop in it and do its own witchcraft. Thats why it works when 'animated', because theres a lot more going on. Probably it doesn't even use 'top:100%' at all. It's probably translating this into `style.top = clientHeight+'px'`